# Storing different size vertices in same vertex/index buffer WebGL

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

say I want to have two different elements in same vertex buffer like

[[x,y,z,u,v],[a,b,c],[x,y,z,u,v]] (for clarity) or [x,y,z,u,v,a,b,c,x,y,z,u,v]

In one draw call only vertices of same size would be used.

`gl.drawElements(gl.LINE_STRIP, 1, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 1);`

That should draw one element starting from index offset 1 but **how do I specify the vertex buffer offset?** As far as I can tell the vertex buffer will point at 3 because of the stride size?

```
   gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionAttribute,3, gl.FLOAT, false, stride=3, 0);
```

What I need is to start from 5, Is that possible or should I keep same size vertices in separate buffers?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `glVertexAttribPointer`? The last argument is the offset.

Comment: as far as i understand it is offset in vertex        gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionAttribute,3, gl.FLOAT, false, stride, 0);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(textureCoordAttribute, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, stride, 3);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexNormalAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, stride, 5); im not sure if i can turn it into a global offset, can i?

Comment: So if i add some offset there, and my old index was like 5,6,7 i would need to adjust the index to be say 1,2,3?

Comment: The offset is in bytes from the start of the buffer. The attribute for vertex 0 is at `offset+0*stride`, for vertex 1 `offset+1*stride`, etc.

Comment: Just to be clear about this: when you say elements, do you mean elements like `gl.DrawElements` or do you mean attributes? If the latter, what do you expect to happen when you've some vertices that have certain attributes and some that do not? What's the use case?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo care to post an answer so i can accept? I had wrong idea of how  glVertexAttribPointer works, like i said i thougt it means relative offset in vertex when it actually is offset for first index element. Before I increased index for each new chunk i put in to buffer so my index data would be like [[0],[1],[2]] and call glVertexAttribPointer once after switching program. Now I have every index chunk start with 0 so it looks like [[0],[0],[0]] and call glVertexAttribPointer before each draw with correct offset in vertex buffer

Comment: @Tommy by elements i mean objects, data collections not sure how to call them. Think 3 models loaded in the example each has one vertice. In my particular case there is line data with 3 values per vertex and textured model data with 5.